# How to delete some associations from an ActiveRecord object without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have:

```
@project = Project.last
@project.tasks = @project.tasks.reject{|o| o.stupid? }

# Do more stuff
```

When I update the tasks array, it actually saves it which we don't want.

How do we prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

The `save` happens when you reassign the result to `@project.tasks`.

Just don't reassign it, and use `reject!` to change the original `@project.tasks`:

```
@project = Project.last
@project.tasks.reject!{ |o| o.stupid? }
```

Comment: The issue is we actually wanna assign it (the reason is complex) but that's what we wanna do :(

Comment: @Ryan Try use `reject!` instead.