# Removing associations when calling collection.build - Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to remove records from a `has_many` association without saving the model similar to how [collection.build](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/build) can add associations without saving.
There doesn't seem to be a key you can add to a hash to designate a record for removal when using `collection.build` like `:_delete` for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. And there doesn't seem to be another method that can be used.

I found this solution:
[How to delete some associations from an ActiveRecord object without saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927284/how-to-delete-some-associations-from-an-activerecord-object-without-saving)
but it doesn't seem to work (or at least not anymore) as collection proxies do not have a `reject!` method.

Comment: Why do you need to delete without saving?

Comment: I run into some issues with my validations without it. The situation is along the lines of:
There's a model A that belongs to model B and has many of model C. And B has one A and has many C also. 
There's a validation rule in A that checks to make sure that it's C and the C associated with the B that's associated with the A are kept in sync. So I have to remove an element of C from both A and B before saving either of them or it throws an error.
Hopefully, that simplification didn't also remove the issue haha.
Obviously, the models are a little weird so maybe that's a larger problem.

Comment: Although I ended up being able to change a few things around so I could use accepts_nested_attributes_for, so I'm no longer stuck. But I think it's still an interesting question... I think.

Comment: "And B has one A and has many C also." I hope `B has_many :C, through: :A`? In this case you don't need to validate or sync anything

Comment: That's a good point. I forgot to mention that it's okay for the associations to be nil so A could have no B associated with it, but still have C's and the same is true for B having no A. But if they're associated together the C's need to be sync'ed.

Comment: Yes, looks like it is a larger problem than just `remove associated before deletion`. Which model is main here? I mean, what is direction of syncing? If, for example, A has `relation1` of Cs, B has `relation2` of Cs, and A becomes associated  with B - which relation of Cs should they have? Looks like you need not a validation here, but some logic of updating A/B after save of B/A.